# In Android, How can I consume NFC actions without having a foreground activity =

Tags: android, service, nfc

I'm trying to read a nfc tag in the background and then save the read message in a file.  However, the only way i found is having an activity on top.  I also tried with a service but  the NfcAdapter cannot directly communicate with android services using ACTIONS.

Answer (score 1):

Only Activities can receive NFC intents. There is no way for a background task or a service to receive them. This is an intentional design choice, I think. It always gives the user full control, just like with the Android Beam screen that the user has to tap before any data is shared over NFC.